# how can I see image fullscreen in python?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, screen

I am viewing the image on the screen using open cv in python. But the image which I opened with the code is halfway on the screen. But I want you to look full screen. How can I do that? Could you help?

Comment: uhhh maybe have you tried resizing the image equal to the resolution of your screen?

Comment: You should add a screenshot to make it more clear what you're asking for

Comment: Create a named window with the [fullscreen](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ggabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3a78bc64121f612562bbb2fa23d316e84e) property set...

Comment: thanks a lot for your contributions. This solution is  solved

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
cv2.namedWindow("WindowName",cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow("WindowName",output_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

First you have to create a `namedWindow` with full screen property. Property you should use is `cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` from [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a window manually and resize it. For example:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Image",WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv2.resizeWindow("Image",1366,768); //Enter your size
cv2.imshow("Image",frame);
```

If the image is not display on a full screen, then resize image using command *cv2.resize()*! Good luck!